# How to return map with different comparator in C++?

Tags: c++

If I have a class with 2 `std::map` properties, both with different comparators, then how can I write a function to return either of them?
E.g.:

```cpp
class Test {
public:
  std::map<int, int> &get_map(int id) {
    if (id == 1)
      return map_1;
    else
      return map_2;
  }

private:
  std::map<int, int, std::less<int>> map_1;
  std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>> map_2;
};
```

Here the compiler will fail because `map_2` is not `std::map<int, int>`.
I also tried `std::map<int, int, std::binary_function<int, int, bool>>` as the return type, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You can't. Create two getter function instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to write your own comparator with parameter:

```
struct Cmp {
    Cmp(bool is_less) : is_less(is_less)
    {}

    bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs) const { 
        if (is_less) {
            return lhs < rhs;
        } else {
            return lhs > rhs;
        }
    }

private:
    bool is_less;
};
```

Now you can use it in both of `std::map` with different value of `is_less` parameter:

```
class Test {
public:
  Test() :
    map_1(Cmp(true)),
    map_2(Cmp(false))
  {}

  std::map<int, int, Cmp> &get_map(int id) {
    if (id == 1)
      return map_1;
    else
      return map_2;
  }

private:
  std::map<int, int, Cmp> map_1;
  std::map<int, int, Cmp> map_2;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to write a function that can return either directly, because they have a different type (with no common base class). You can however have a function template:

```
template<class Comp>
std::map<int, int, Comp>& get_map();
```

Here, `id` is redundant because the member is identified by the template argument.

---

Or you could wrap a pointer to either in a tagged union, and return that. For example:

```
std::variant<
    std::map<int, int, std::less<int>>*,
    std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>>*
>
get_map(int id);
```

---

Object oriented approach could be to not provide a getter at all, and only operate on the maps within the class.

Comment: I would write an answer using `reference_wrapper` but yours is better

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You cannot.

Templates are just templates. Different instantiations of templates are different types. If `map` would be your type, then you could make different instantiations inherit from a common base and use them polymorphically. However, `std::map` is not your type, so you cannot do that. You could return a `std::variant`, but writing two getters is much easier.

Last but not least, note that if you return a non-const reference to a private member, then there is practiaclly no encapsulation. You could as well make the members public, which will also eliminate your current problem.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, you might erase comparer type, to have same map type:

```
class Test {
public:
  std::map<int, int, bool (*)(int, int)> &get_map(int id) {
      return (id == 1) ? map_1 : map_2;
  }

private:
  std::map<int, int, bool (*)(int, int)> map_1 = {+[](int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs < rhs; }};
  std::map<int, int, bool (*)(int, int)> map_2 = {+[](int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs > rhs; }};
};
```